# Is this a t sql stored proceedure

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to execute this from within Excel (SQL query window) where I would normally only execute the select statement.  Should I make it into a stored proceedure and then execute tat from within Excel?

```
BEGIN TRY

    drop table GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_hist_dtl_Quote 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

END CATCH

BEGIN TRY

    drop table GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_lines_Quote 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

END CATCH


select * into GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_hist_dtl_Quote 
from GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_hist_dtl where isnull(USER_3,'') <> ''  
select * into GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_lines_Quote 
from GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_lines where isnull(USER_3,'') <> ''  



/* Quotes with Orders 1.0 */ 
select 
QT.QuoteNum, 
QT.custID, 
QT.QCustNum, 
QT.QCustName, 
QT.QDate, 
COUNT(OL.order_no) as #_Open_Orders, 
COUNT(OH.order_no) as #_Closed_Orders
from 
"Track Quotes".dbo.TrackQuotesHist as QT 
left outer join GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_hist_dtl_quote as OH 
on QT.QuoteNum = OH.USER_3 
left outer join GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_lines_quote as OL 
on QT.QuoteNum = OL.USER_3 
where 
QT.QDate between '03/01/2015' and '03/06/2015'
Group By  
QT.QuoteNum, 
QT.custID, 
QT.QCustNum, 
QT.QCustName, 
QT.QDate
```

Comment: Yes that would be an excellent candidate for a stored procedure. Your code however has two extremely MAJOR flaws. You have two catch blocks that are empty. This is awful idea. This is NOT handling errors, it is suppressing them. Why bother capturing an error if you don't care if it happened or not?

Comment: The intent is to drop the tables if there are there, then create new ones and then run the report.  I am not interested in running a seperate script if there tables are not there, just keep going.

Comment: In that case I would use sql in your procedure instead of an empty catch. That is a huge red flag when you first see it. Especially if the error is a permissions error, the rest of your code could still fail.

Comment: So if there is a permissions problem then the TRY drop tables will fail and then so will the select into.  Without seeing the error then my query result will be based on an old temp table and I won't know it.  Good point; I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my world I assume an object that starts with v_ is a view but you seem to treat it as a table and if it is change it to something like this:

```
create proc dbo.procfiles
as
BEGIN  
    if object_id('GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_hist_dtl_Quote','U') is not null
      drop table GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_hist_dtl_Quote 

    if object_id('GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_lines_Quote','U') is not null
       drop table GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_lines_Quote 

select * into GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_hist_dtl_Quote 
from GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_hist_dtl where user_3 is not null  

select * into GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_lines_Quote 
from GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_lines where user_3 is not null    

/* Quotes with Orders 1.0 */ 
select 
QT.QuoteNum, 
QT.custID, 
QT.QCustNum, 
QT.QCustName, 
QT.QDate, 
COUNT(OL.order_no) as #_Open_Orders, 
COUNT(OH.order_no) as #_Closed_Orders
from 
"Track Quotes".dbo.TrackQuotesHist as QT 
left outer join GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_hist_dtl_quote as OH 
on QT.QuoteNum = OH.USER_3 
left outer join GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_lines_quote as OL 
on QT.QuoteNum = OL.USER_3 
where 
QT.QDate between '03/01/2015' and '03/06/2015'
Group By  
QT.QuoteNum, 
QT.custID, 
QT.QCustNum, 
QT.QCustName, 
QT.QDate 

begin catch 
select
ERROR_NUMBER(),
            ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            ERROR_STATE(),
            ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
            ERROR_LINE(),
            ERROR_MESSAGE()
end catch

end
```

Comment: I agree.  These are actual tables mirrored from a pervasive database views.  Like I said above, I only use the try and catch to drop the tables if they exist; not interested in knowing if there did or not.  I have to change my original question.  I would only want the drop tables and create new ones in the procedure because the select statement will come from within Excel with a dynamic parameter for the date range.  I store the SQL code in a sheet with embedded functions for dynamic parameter like this: ="QT.QDate between '"&TEXT(QuoFrom,"mm/dd/yyy")&"' and '"&TEXT(QuoTo,"mm/dd/yyy")&"' ".

Comment: The logic is that if the tables exist drop them. Then you can safely select into. Please mark one, or more, of the answers as acceptable if you like the answer(s).

Comment: So I would want to create a procedure then execute that from within Excel prior to the select statement.

Comment: This procedure will both create the tables and do the select. What select are you referring to?

Comment: I apologize that my question was flawed.  The only part that I would want in the procedure is the try drop tables and select into tables to create new ones.  The select under /* Quotes with Order 1.0*/ is the report which will generate from within Excel via ODBC connection.

Comment: Put what you want in the proc and execute the rest in Excel. You may want to change the catch part (which executes when SQL Server detects an error) to store the error information into a table that you can look at when you need to.

Comment: If I just use TRY to drop the table then I get an error.  If I combine TRY with an empty CATCH then it works - drops tables if they are there and continues on either way.  This is exactly what I want to do; no more or less.  That said, I am clearly still learning and very open to best practices.  I had previously research best method for accomplishing that objective is this one seemed to work best.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run the select statements most of the time I would make the drops into one stored procedure (if you ever want to do it) and then the select into another.

Comment: I stuck with my original use of TRY CATCH because it works smoothly and I am not interested in generating an error massage.  I modified my procedure shown below and it works; hurray – my first stored procedure.  My new problem is that I can execute a procedure from within an Excel OLE DB Query window.  I will have to research this separately.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very compelling reason to update those tables every time this query is run, I would avoid them.  Just use equivalent query without the use of the tables:

```
select 
    QT.QuoteNum, 
    QT.custID, 
    QT.QCustNum, 
    QT.QCustName, 
    QT.QDate, 
    COUNT(OL.order_no) as #_Open_Orders, 
    COUNT(OH.order_no) as #_Closed_Orders
from "Track Quotes".dbo.TrackQuotesHist as QT 
left outer join GlGlobalShop.dbo.v_order_hist_dtl OH 
on QT.QuoteNum = OH.USER_3
    and isnull(QT.QuoteNum,'')<>''
left outer join GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_lines OL 
on QT.QuoteNum = OL.USER_3
    and isnull(QT.QuoteNum,'')<>''
where QT.QDate between '03/01/2015' and '03/06/2015' 
Group By  
    QT.QuoteNum, 
    QT.custID, 
    QT.QCustNum, 
    QT.QCustName, 
    QT.QDate
```

Comment: The GlobalShop.dbo.v_order_hist_dtl has over 200k records and the vast majority do not have data in user_3.  Something is up with this server and I'm not going to address it right now, so this is just a work around.  The query you wrote takes over 20 minutes to complete.  Running the entire script as I wrote it takes about 10 seconds.

Comment: Ah, yes I've needed to make performance tweeks like this before.  It's probably a good use for a temporary table.